# List.map fsi is telling ok, but can't build

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Why this piece of code is working on my fsi, but can't build the project?   I am using vs2010 and F# 2.0 ...Any ideas that I am missing something?

```
let arg = [@"C:\Temp\bin"; @"C:\temp\xml"]
arg|> List.map(fun (s) -> printfn "%s" s)
```

getting the error telling that it was expecting int, how?

```
Error 1 
Type mismatch. Expecting a string list -> int but given a string list -> 'a list  
The type 'int' does not match the type ''a list'    
C:\Users\Ebru\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WinFind\WinFind\Program.fs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you actually wrote

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let Main(args) =
    let arg = [@"C:\Temp\bin"; @"C:\temp\xml"] 
    arg|> List.map(fun (s) -> printfn "%s" s)
```

and an `EntryPoint` method (e.g. `Main()`) must return an int.

Answer (score 0):

this snippet compiles on my machine, but the mapping seems weird. I think you really what to do this:

```
let arg = [@"C:\Temp\bin"; @"C:\temp\xml"]
arg|> List.iter (fun s -> printfn "%s" s)
```

which is the same as:

```
let arg = [@"C:\Temp\bin"; @"C:\temp\xml"]
arg|> List.iter (printfn "%s")
```

Regards,
  forki